# What do you call the rubber strip attached to cupboard door?

Tags: bathroom, doors, cabinets

My bathroom has a white cabinet, where one of the doors has an adhesive rubber strip running down the inside of the door.

This is so when both doors are closed, you cant see a big black gap in the space where the door edges meet.

I need to replace one of them, as it has shattered, but Ive no idea what to search for? Do these little babies have a name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably call it a back plate, a span strip or a draft blocker.

I would probably be wrong, but that's what I would call them.  I've never shopped for one on their own, I usually fabricate such things out of strips of hobby wood.